# Need help converting binary number to string in C

Tags: c, string

So I'm trying to convert a binary number into a string using this method

```
//convert input to binary
nTemp = nGiven; //n is a input number
int nTemp;
int nBitCounter = 0;
char str[18];
 char temp[1];

strcpy(str, "0");

 /* count the number of bits of the given number */
for (; nTemp != 0; nBitCounter++)
    nTemp = nTemp >> 1;

/* store the binary number into a string */
for (; nBitCounter>0; nBitCounter--) {
    nTemp = 1 << (nBitCounter - 1);
    int binNum = (nTemp & nGiven) >> (nBitCounter - 1);
    printf("%d", binNum);
    _itoa(binNum, temp, 10);
    strcat(str, temp);
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to do what I want correctly. The printing of binNum is correct but I do not know how to store this binary representation as a string. In the second 'for' loop, I need to store binNum as a character(temp) and then append it to a string(str).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Something like: `str[i++] = binNum ? '1' : '0';` would seem appropriate. As your for `temp` variable, one-element arrays are generally not useful, particularly not for storing non-empty strings.

Comment: Note that if `nTemp` is negative and if `>>` preserves signs, your loop to count the number of bits is going to run for a long time.

Comment: After the question has been answered, just click the accept button, don't delete the whole content like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare temp as:

```
char temp[2];
```

Because you need the byte which will have the null caracter.

Use sprintf() function:

```
sprintf(temp,"%d", binNum);
```

And then:

```
strcat(str, temp);
```

Comment: What would be the easiest way to convert str to an int after doing this? I tried using atoi again but that function never seems to work properly..

Comment: use `strtoul` with `2` as the base to convert this string back to an integral type

Comment: I have always used atoi() function to do that and 0 problems. What is the problem about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
int idx(char cc)
{
  if (cc >= '0' && cc <= '9')
    return cc - '0' ;
  else if (cc >= 'A' && cc < 'F')
    return cc - 'A' + 10 ;
  else
    return cc - 'a' + 10 ;
}

void ConvertToBinary (int value, char *output)
{
   char *digits [] = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", 
                       "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
                       "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
                       "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111", } ;

   char buffer [32] ;
   output [0] = 0 ;

   sprintf (buffer, "%x", value) ;

   int ii ;
   for (ii = 0 ; buffer [ii] != 0 ; ++ ii)
   {

      strcat (output, digits [idx (buffer [ii])]) ;
   }       

   return ;
}
```

I also point out that your str buffer is too small.

Answer (score 0):

The question code is very close.

The following code works:

```
int nGiven = 0x1234;    //n is a input number   
int nTemp;
int nBitCounter=0;
char str[18];
char temp[2];

strcpy(str, "0");

/* count the number of bits of the given number */
for(nTemp=nGiven; nTemp; nBitCounter++)
    nTemp = nTemp >> 1;

/* store the binary number into a string */
for(; nBitCounter; nBitCounter--)
   {
   int binNum;

   nTemp = 1 << (nBitCounter - 1);
   binNum = (nTemp & nGiven) >> (nBitCounter - 1);
// _itoa(binNum, temp, 10);
```

I don't have access to a function called '_itoa()'; so use snprintf() instead.

```
   snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%d", binNum);
   strcat(str, temp);
   }

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be. Assuming you want to drop leading zeroes as your code seems to indicate:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int nTemp = 123456789;
    char buf[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 1];
    char *ptr = buf;

    for ( int i = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int); i--; )
    {
       if ( nTemp & (1u << i) )
           *ptr++ = '1';
       else if ( ptr != buf )
           *ptr++ = '0';
    }
    *ptr = 0;

    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

This will give a blank string for input of `0`, you can change that by checing `if (ptr == buf)` at the end and taking action.

Answer (score -2):

```
char * temp;

.....

temp = malloc(nBitCounter + 1);
temp[nBitCounter] = '\0';

for (; nBitCounter > 0; nBitCounter--) {
//  get the binNum by nBitCounter;
    temp[nBitCounter - 1] = binNum + '0';  // if 0, you get '0'; if 1, you get '1'
}

strcat(str, temp);
free(temp);
```

Comment: Not my down-vote, but you've not shown how to extract the bits in the body of the loop, an you've not ensured that the string is null terminated, and it isn't clear that you've allocated enough space for the terminating null, and you've not described what you're doing at all.  Fixing all of those would radically improve what is currently a not useful answer.

Comment: I've just realized that I had forgotten the terminating null and edited it just now. You are right.

Comment: Another problem, the bin number should be convert to ASC code